# Can't find Time Capsule and AirPort Express through my wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, airport, time-capsule

I have recently gotten a new router for internet, but sadly it hasn't been much of an improvement to my network.

I own a Time Capsule and an AirPort Express. They are both hooked up to my wireless router which is a Zyxel P-2812HNU-F1.

The problem is that I can't find them in my Airport Utility. It is very frustrating. I have reset them both, I can find them then, but as soon as they connect to wireless internet, they are gone. The interesting thing is, when I configure them in AirPort Utility with their IP addresses, they work. But otherwise they don't.

This way I can't connect to my Time Capsule. Any any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why aren't you using the wireless network run by either the Time Capsule or the AirPort Express?

Comment: I am using the wireless network, I just have the router elsewhere in the house and the time capsule connected through the wireless